# Name a series of directories after file names

Tags: shell-script, command-line

I have a list of files named EX5_##.bak.  I want to each one in a directory named EX5_##.
Example

```
EX5_01.bak
EX5_02.bak
EX5_03.bak
```

and I want to put them in directories.  So when I typy

```
ls -l
```

I get :

```
EX5_01
EX5_02
EX5_03
```

and so forth where those are directory names and the files of the same name are in the directory.  How do I go about this?  Is there a single command or Bash script that I can write to achieve this?

Comment: You want to what? “I want to each one in a directory …”.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple shell loop:

```
#!/bin/sh

for file in ./EX5_??.bak; do
    dir=${file%.bak}
    mkdir -p "$dir" && mv -i "$file" "$dir"
done
```

This would iterate over all your `EX5_??.bak` files in the current directory (`?` matches a single character). For each file, it creates a directory name by stripping the `.bak` suffix off from the filename (this is what `${file%.bak}` does).  It then creates the directory if it did not already exist and, if there was no issue with creating the directory, moves the file over into it.

If you need to be more precise with the selection of files, you may want to use `./EX5_[0-9][0-9].bak` as the pattern to iterate over.  This could be useful if you also have files like `EX5_AA.bak` that you *don't* want to include in the loop.

The `-p` option to `mkdir` makes the utility not treat it as an error that the directory already exists (it also makes it create intermediate directories, but that's not really used in this instance).

The `-i` option to `mv` makes it ask for confirmation before overwriting any files in the target directory.  We use it here as a safety catch.

Comment: Thank you.  This will be helpful not just for this application but gives me a frame work for other things as well.  Can you run this from the command line or do I have to make it a script?

Comment: @Jay You _could_ run this on the command line, but it would be more suited as a shell script.  If you just copy and paste it into a terminal, it would execute, likewise if you just typed it in, line for line. It would be safer to write it in a shell script though, as you would be able to read it a few times to make sure that you got everything correctly.

Comment: @Jay Also, note that you should never use code that you don't understand, no matter where it comes from.

Comment: As I always do...I go line by line and understand what each command does. While relatively new to Linux and the command line I do understand what some of this does.  Thanks for your explanation and time.